# Can two razor page application use the same database and use code first?

Tags: .net, razor, razor-pages

I've created a long term planning application in razor pages.

This application is only built to handle the long term planning. And is build around a projects model in my razor page application.

Now I want to add some functionality that keeps track of attributes in the project that don't belong to long term planning. I don't need all the pages from the ***long term planning*** application, but I need some of the data that's stored in the database of the long term planning application.

My question is, can I build a second razor pages application that uses the same database and models as the ***long term planning*** application. And if i do so, do i need to copy the models back and fort if i want to change something to the application.

Or is there a better way to do this.

Tried to explain is at simple as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the model and data access out to their own class library projects, and then reference those projects in both the existing long term planning application and the new application.

If you want to make changes to the model or database / data access, both projects will see the changes.